# Confusion in if else logic condition

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
if (filesxt.Extension.ToString()==".rar")
{
    NUnrar.Archive.RarArchive.WriteToDirectory(Sourcepath, Destination, 
        NUnrar.Common.ExtractOptions.ExtractFullPath | 
        NUnrar.Common.ExtractOptions.Overwrite);
}
else if (filesxt.Extension.ToString() == ".zip") 
{
    UnZipFromMTAThread(Sourcepath, Destination);
}
```

When the file extension is **.rar** and `NUnrar.Archive.RarArchive.WriteToDirectory` throws an exception, I want to execute the below method instead:

```
ExtractFile(Sourcepath, Destination);
```

How can I do that? Can anyone help?

Comment: what about `.ZIP` or `.Zip` ?

Comment: What is `filesxt`? What method is throwing error? Please read through the help section on how to ask a question.

Comment: Well you can use `try/catch` to detect and handle errors...

Comment: @musefan Worst advise ever!

Comment: @UweKeim: Why is that?

Comment: @musefan Giving someone who struggles with `if/else` the advise to use `try/catch` is like giving your two years old a butcher knife and a shotgun.

Comment: @UweKeim: Why are they struggling with `if/else`? What is wrong with their code?

Comment: @musefan Please keep it friendly.

Comment: @musefan is correct though. Samsam is asking how he should execute another method if the .rar method fails. Failure would lead to an exception of some sort, hence he suggested a try catch.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks. Ideally there would be a better way to test if it was going to fail without catching exceptions, but if you can't expect failure then you have to handle the exception instead.

Comment: I am not even sure why this question is closed... it's a pretty clear question (if you actually read it). I am going to nominate to re-open unless someone can give a decent reason why it should stay closed?

Comment: Hello. Sorry if the question was unclear.

Comment: @Samsam: The question makes sense, I don't know why they closed it. I can't post an answer (because the question is closed), but take a look at [`try/catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch). You put your `WriteToDirectory` in the `try` block, and then if it errors (throws an exception) you can call `ExtractFile` in the `catch` block

Comment: oh okay. thanks Man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you  need to handle an unexpected exception in code, then you can use a [`try/catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch).

To put this simply, you basically say "**try** this bit of code, and if an exception occurs then **catch** the exception and do a different bit of code".

So you want to put your `WriteToDirectory` call in the *try*, and then your `ExtractFile` in the *catch*.

Something like this should work for what you need:

```
try
{
    NUnrar.Archive.RarArchive.WriteToDirectory(Sourcepath, Destination, 
        NUnrar.Common.ExtractOptions.ExtractFullPath | 
        NUnrar.Common.ExtractOptions.Overwrite);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ExtractFile(Sourcepath, Destination);
}
```